# MySQL select multiple distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-workbench, distinct

I have columns email,city, address, state, country in a MySQL database. 
some of the emails have multiple addresses.(multiple addresses and states)- different rows for different addresses with same email.
I want my result set to display count of distinct email and state and group the the count based on state.

I tried stuff like-

```
select count(distinct(email), state from A group by state
```

but due to multiple addresses the same email shows up in multiple states. 
How do make the email show up only on any one state only?
Can anybody help out here?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help us understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` cannot contain two operands. You can use `GROUP BY`.

```
select email, state from A group by email, state
```

If you need a COUNT from of the above, you can put it in a subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (select email, state from A group by email, state) TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.email, f.state, f.id from(
select email, max(id) as maxid
from addresses where country= 'US' 
group by email) as x inner join addresses as f on f.email=x.email and f.id=x.maxid;
```

Thank you for the help. This query answered my question.